# How to see my hats from winter bashes 2013 & 2014?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I remember last year there was a possibility to see my hats even after the winter-bash has ended. I would like to see them again. How can I see the hats I earned in winter bashes 2013 and 2014?

PS: not a duplicate of that question, I don't want to see my performance/rankings, I want to see the hats I earned. And it WAS possible shortly after the winter-bash ended, so it's likely to still be possible now.

Comment: the answer in the "duplicate" is unsatisfactory!

Comment: True, but it doesn't justify leaving open dupes around.